# All angularJs templateUrl paths invalid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, angular-ui-router

So I'm writing a small app and currently working on the angular js front end. The backend is written in RoR but thats besides the point. I have a dependency `ui.router` in my `angular.module` so I can move around pages.

Link to github branch if interested: [linky link](https://github.com/JeffreyCheng92/SwoleMetrics/tree/router)

Paths:

```
App
  -Assets
    -Javascripts
      -app.js (where the routing lies)
    -Templates
      -dashboard.html (this is the template I want to render)
  -Views
    -Layouts
      -Index.html.erb <- this is the index
```

Heres the problem:

```
angular.module('SwoleMetrics', [
        'ui.router',
        'templates'
    ])
    .config(function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {
      /**
       * Routes and States
       */
      $stateProvider
          .state('dashboard', {
              url: '/dashboard',
              templateUrl: 'dashboard.html', <<--- RIGHT HERE
              controller: 'DashboardCtrl'
      });

      // default fall back route
      $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/dashboard');

      // enable HTML5 Mode for SEO
      $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    });
```

No matter what path I put into templateUrl, it never works. I have the same html file in basically every folder around app.js to see if it could read any of those but it always fails and just recursively inserts the parent div into the . Do any front end engineers know why?

Comment: did you tried `templateUrl: '/Templates/dashboard.html'`?

Comment: @PankajParkar, yes it did not work. It just nests the parent div within itself

Answer (score 1):

The issue was the way the files were being served via rails. The sprockets gem was updated and no longer compatible with angular-ui-templates and broke everything. Downgraded to sprockets v. 2.x and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Its going to be relative to index.html. If index.html is under App then your path is going to be templateUrl: 'Templates/dashboard.html'.

Comment: Does not work, Ive tried every rendition of templates and dashboard in all the javascripts folder and none of them work.

Comment: I've edited the folder skeleton to show where the index.html is.

Comment: Not sure how your serving the page but you'd have to go up 2 directories ../../Assets/Templates/dashboard.html

Comment: do you know if I need to go up 2 directories from the index.html or from the app.js where the router lives?

Comment: It would be from index.html but depending on your web server you might not be able to.